# counting totals after left join and requiring 0 for a NULL variable - SQL Server

Tags: sql, join, count, null

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and I am running the following query:

```
SELECT T1.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE) AS [TOTAL_APPOINTMENTS]
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE > '2019-01-01' AND T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE < '2020-01-01'
AND (T1.ID = 1 OR T1.ID = 2 OR T1.ID = 3)
```

I would like the total number of appointments for these 3 individuals for now. Then, I will include everyone in Table 1. Table 1 gives me the ID (one row per individual), Table 2 gives me all appointments across different days per individual.

The results I get are:

```
ID  TOTAL_APPOINTMENTS
1         12
2         3
```

But I would like:

```
ID  TOTAL_APPOINTMENTS
1         12
2         3
3         0
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` conditions on the *second* table to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT T1.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE) AS [TOTAL_APPOINTMENTS]
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND
        T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE > '2019-01-01' AND
        T2.APPOINTMENT_DATE < '2020-01-01'
WHERE T1.ID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Note that the conditions on the *first* table remain in the `WHERE` clause.  Also, `IN` is simpler than a bunch of `OR` conditions.